# Triggers zabbix

Tags: triggers, zabbix

Good morning,

I would like to create a trigger in Zabbix with a value range. On paper, this is it:

- [0 2] = red "error"
- ]2 4] = orange "alarm"
- ]4 6] = yellow "alert"
- ]6 infinity = green "ok"

But I don’t know what correct expression to take in Zabbix. Do you know what expression and how to correctly enter these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first trigger in your list, `[0 2]`, legacy trigger format (before Zabbix 5.4):

`{template:item.last()} >= 0 and {template:item.last()} <=2`

current trigger format:

`last(/template/item) >=0 and last(/template/item)<=0`